# android - TextView won't update in UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

```
//This is the TextViewExample class
public class TextViewExample {

private TextView mTextViewExample;

public TextViewExample(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mTextViewExample = (TextView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.TextViewLayout);
    } 
}

//This is the Fragment class
public class TextViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextViewExample mText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mText = new TextViewExample(getActivity());
    }
}
```

`mText` is not updated in the UI! Could someone explain the correct way of displaying `TextView` properly from calling an activity in a fragment.

Thanks =)

Comment: you can access the `TextView` in `onCrateView` directly by `findViewById`, why do you use `TextViewExample` ?

Comment: Did you call setContentView(..) in the Activity that you pass as a parameter to your class ?

Comment: you haven't inflated any out & if you want to create a dynamic TextView then you need to add it in your layout. I am not seeing any particular android standard followed.. please learn basics of android & fragment..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Activity's `TextView` in the Fragment (assuming this fragment is attached to the activity) directly:

```
//This is the Fragment class
public class TextViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView mText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // you need to inflate the xml file holding this TextView.
        mText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewByid(R.id.<your-text-view-id>;
        // do something with your TextView
    }
}
```

Be sure to check for `getActivity() == null` to avoid NPE's.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity:**

```
 public class MainActivity {

    private TextView mTextViewExample;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mTextViewExample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewLayout);
        } 
    }

    public void setTextViewExampleText(String text) {
        mTextViewExample.setText(text);
    }
```

**TextViewFragment**

```
public class TextViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTextViewExampleText("text");
    }
}
```